# C: Wait for brothers process termination

Tags: c, wait

My program have to create n childs. When a signal is recieved a child is created. Then the first child wait for the others n-1 childs. The second one wait for the other n-2 childs and so on until the last child run and finish immediately. 
I write this code, but it don't work and i get nephews.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void func(int sign)
{
    printf("received signal. I create a child\n");
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int i,pid,status;
    int n=atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned int m=(unsigned int)atoi(argv[2]);
    signal(SIGALRM,func);
    printf("i'm father: pid %d\n",getpid());
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        alarm(m);
        pause();
        switch(pid=fork())
        {
        case -1:
            printf("error\n");
            break;
        case 0: 
            printf("i'm the hild numer %d, my pid is %d\n",i,getpid());
            if(i!=n-1)
            {
                wait(NULL);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d i have fnished\n",getpid());
                exit(0);
            }
            break;
        default:
            wait(NULL); 
            break;
        }
     }
     printf("finish\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The correct term is to call it a `child process`

Comment: You're going to need some way to pass all the child IDs to all the children. Otherwise the second child will have no way of waiting for all the children that haven't yet been created...

Comment: All the child processes are being started by the father process.  The wait() function only waits on children of the *current*  process.  The code executed by the last child created will terminate, (none of the other children terminate) causing the father to terminate (all the other children are still holding on a 'wait(NULL)' )  I.E. all the children need some logic to cause them to terminate.  One way is a common variable that the father initializes to have the children keep executing, then after all children generated, reset the variable so the children terminate.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is structured, you are creating `2^N` processes.

You need to change the code under:

```
default:
   wait(NULL);
   break;
```

to something that does not fork any more children after that. One way to do that is using a `goto` statement. Here's an updated version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void func(int sign)
{
   printf("received signal. I create a child\n");
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
   if(argc!=3)
   {
      printf("error\n");
      return 0;
   }
   int i,pid,status;
   int n=atoi(argv[1]);
   unsigned int m=(unsigned int)atoi(argv[2]);
   signal(SIGALRM,func);
   printf("i'm father: pid %d\n",getpid());
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      alarm(m);
      pause();
      switch(pid=fork())
      {
         case -1:
            printf("error\n");
            break;

         case 0:
            printf("i'm the child numer %d, my pid is %d\n",i,getpid());
            if(i!=n-1)
            {
               wait(NULL);
               break;
            }
            else
            {
               printf("%d i have fnished\n",getpid());
               exit(0);
            }
            break;

         default:
            wait(NULL);
            goto done;
      }
   }

done:
   printf("%d i have fnished\n",getpid());
   return 0;
}
```